# Android FragmentDialog's state and device rotation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

`AlertDialog` with `DialogFragment` will restore any data (edited text in text view's, chosen element in single choice) after device rotation. And will not restore checked items in multichoice mode. To be accurate - it will remember fields initiated with `false` and always reset fields initiated with `true` (reset back to true after rotate).

That is very strange, what am i doing wrong? I want it to restore all data (especially when all the views managed by dialog itself).

**UPD 1**: I actually understand, that i can track any user interaction with UI in dialog and save it between dialog/fragment instances in bundles or even static variables. BUT it **already manage** to save my custom layout's state (edittext+checkbox) and singlechoice selection **by itself**. And **only multichoice behaves wrong** with similar code. That is what i want to understand.

Working demo below.
Tested on Nexus 5 / Android 4.4.2

Activity with only one method implemented

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button single  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.single);
    single.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            df_single newDialog = new df_single();
            newDialog.show(MyActivity.this.getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    });
    Button multi  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multi);
    multi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            df_multi newDialog = new df_multi();
            newDialog.show(MyActivity.this.getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    });
}
```

It's layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:id="@+id/single" android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="list single"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/multi" android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="list multi"/>
```

DialogFragment for single choice

```
public class df_single extends DialogFragment {
public df_single() {    }

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Single");
    String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 1, null);
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

DialogFragment for multi choice

```
public class df_multi extends DialogFragment {
public df_multi() {    }

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Multi");
    String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    boolean[] checked = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false, true};
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checked, null);
    Dialog answer = builder.create();
    return answer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can persist the selected element using onSaveInstanceState method and restore the selected element position.

```
public class df_single extends DialogFragment {
    public df_single() {    }
    public static final int DEFAULT_ELEMENT_POSITION;
    int selectedElement;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Single");
        selectedElement = savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedElement", DEFAULT_ELEMENT_POSITION);
        String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, selectedElement, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        selectedElement = which;
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        savedInstanceState.putInt("selectedElement", selectedElement);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

}

Comment: Please look at my UPD 1.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I can achieve desired behavior (init once and recreate universally on each rotation, get result in positive button clickListener and do not preserve state by myself) with the following code modifications

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Multi");

    final String[] items = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    boolean[] checked = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false, true};

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View listRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    builder.setView(listRoot);

    final ListView list = (ListView)listRoot.findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, android.R.id.text1, items);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    for (int i = 0; i < checked.length; i++)
        list.setItemChecked(i, checked[i]);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
            View view = ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.list);
            assert view != null;
            assert view instanceof ListView;
            SparseBooleanArray checked = ((ListView) view).getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                Log.d("checked", checked.get(i)?"YES":"NO");
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Where `list.xml` is just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That is semi-answer, cause i still don't know what is the difference for android bewtween `setSingleChoiceItems` and `setMultiChoiceItems` in context of state auto save.